# React Navigation doesn't change screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to navigate to another screen (Artist) by clicking on an element in a FlatList. This FlatList contains Artist instances, as set in the _renderListItem method. So far I've tried **three** different approaches (two of them commented out at the moment), but none of them seem to work:

**Method 1: NavigationActions**

**Method 2: this.props.navigation.navigate**

**Method 3: Navigator.push**

I managed to pass the params to the other screen, but unfortunately the navigation itself doesn't seem to work; I'm getting the expected values in my logs, but nothing happens and the app stays at LinksScreen (doesn't change screens).

**LinksScreen.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { PropTypes } from 'prop-types';
import Artist  from './Artist';
import { createStackNavigator, withNavigation, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';
import {
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  FlatList,
  ActivityIndicator,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TouchableHighlight,
} from 'react-native';

export default class LinksScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._onAlertTypePressed = this._onAlertTypePressed.bind(this);
  }

  _onAlertTypePressed(typeId: string, typeName: string, imageUrl: string) {
    console.log(typeId)
    console.log(typeName)
    console.log(imageUrl)

// NavigationActions
    // NavigationActions.navigate({
    //                 routeName: 'Artist',
    //                 params: { itemId: typeId, itemName: typeName, itemImageUrl: imageUrl,},
    //               });

// NAVIGATE
     this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeStack',{},
     {
       type: "Navigate",
       routeName: "Artist",
       params: {
         itemId: typeId,
         itemName: typeName,
         itemImageUrl: imageUrl}
             }
           );

// PUSH
  //     this.props.navigator.push({
  //       screen: 'Artist',
  //       title: 'Artist',
  //       passProps: {
  //         itemId: typeId,
  //         itemName: typeName,
  //         itemImageUrl: imageUrl,
  //       },
  //     });
  }

  _renderListItem = ({item}) => (
    <Artist
      itemId={item.id}
      itemName={item.title.rendered}
      itemImageUrl={
        item.better_featured_image
          ? item.better_featured_image.source_url
          : 'http://54.168.73.151/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/brand-logo.jpg'
      }
      onPressItem={this._onAlertTypePressed}
    />
  );

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Links',
  };

  state = {
    data: [],
    isLoading: true,
    isError: false,
  };

  // static propTypes = {
  //   navigation: PropTypes.shape({
  //     navigate: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  //   }).isRequired,
  // };

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch('http://54.168.73.151/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?parent=38&per_page=100')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        responseJson.sort(
          (a, b) => (a.title.rendered < b.title.rendered ? -1 : 1)
        );
        this.setState({
          data: responseJson,
          isLoading: false,
          isError: false,
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          isError: true,
        });
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

// Not used anymore.
  renderRow = item => (
    <View style={styles.grid}>
      <Image
        style={styles.thumb}
        source={{
          uri: item.better_featured_image
            ? item.better_featured_image.source_url
            : 'http://54.168.73.151/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/brand-logo.jpg',
        }}
      />
      <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title.rendered}</Text>
    </View>
  );

  getKey = item => String(item.id);

  renderComponent() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return <ActivityIndicator />;
    } else if (this.state.isError) {
      return <Text>Error loading data</Text>;
    } else {
      return (
        <FlatList
          numColumns={3}
          contentContainerStyle={styles.elementsContainer}
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={this._renderListItem}
          keyExtractor={this.getKey}
        />
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 20,
            color: '#FFFFFF',
            marginLeft: 4,
            marginTop: 10,
          }}>
          RESIDENTS
        </Text>
        {this.renderComponent()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
  },
  elementsContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
  },
  grid: {
    marginTop: 15,
    marginBottom: 15,
    marginLeft: 5,
    height: 125,
    width: 115,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: '#191970',
  },
  title: {
    color: '#FFFFFF',
    textAlign: 'left',
    fontSize: 12,
  },
  thumb: {
    height: 110,
    width: 110,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
  },
});
```

**Artist.js**

The console.log in the beginning of the `_onPress()` method seem to be working (the expected params have the correct values here), but I'm unable to navigate to this screen.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import {
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';

class Artist extends React.PureComponent {

  _onPress = () => {
     // console.log(this.props)

     const itemId = this.props.itemId
     const itemName = this.props.itemName
     const itemImageUrl = this.props.itemImageUrl

    console.log(itemId)
    console.log(itemName)
    console.log(itemImageUrl)

// FOR PUSH
  //   this.props.onPressItem(
  //     this.props.itemid,
  //     this.props.itemName,
  //     this.props.itemImageUrl,
  //   );
  // };
}

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Artist',
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        {...this.props}
        style={styles.grid}
        onPress={this._onPress}>
        <Image
          style={styles.image}
          source={{uri: this.props.itemImageUrl}}
        />
        <Text style={styles.title}>{this.props.itemName}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
  },
  grid: {
    marginTop: 15,
    marginBottom: 15,
    marginLeft: 5,
    height: 125,
    width: 115,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: '#191970',
  },
  title: {
    color: '#FFFFFF',
    textAlign: 'left',
    fontSize: 12,
  },
  image: {
    height: 110,
    width: 110,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
  },
});

export default Artist;
```

**MainTabNavigator.js**

Perhaps there is something wrong regarding the routing, so here is how it's done in my case.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform, AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import TabBarIcon from '../components/TabBarIcon';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import LinksScreen from '../screens/LinksScreen';
import SettingsScreen from '../screens/SettingsScreen';
import Artist from '../screens/Artist';

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
  },
  Links: {
    screen: LinksScreen,
  },
  Artist: {
    screen: Artist,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ParamsRepo', () => HomeStack);

export default HomeStack;
```

Comment: Where do you want to navigate actually? You have Artist screen mentioned in Navigator and you are rendering Artist in FlatList! Code seems to be more confusing.

Comment: I want to navigate to the Artist screen. I'm rendering the FlatList with Artist objects as well to fill the list of Artists on the LinksScreen.

Comment: I think you are complicating the navigation part, try using it what below answer says. You don't want to navigate to HomeStack and then Artist. You can navigate to Artist directly and you are mixing objects and strings with navigate function.  https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#navigate-link-to-other-screens

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work when I try the solution below. I changed more variant before (as mentioned in the post), but nothing seems to work; the navigation itself doesn't happen, while all required elements are still available in the `_onPress` method in Artist.js (so that part gets triggered).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try simplyfying your code like this:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Artist',
    {
     itemId: typeId,
     itemName: typeName,
     itemImageUrl: imageUrl
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't change anything.

Comment: there is also another issue that I see. You pass the navigation action using onPressItem but you never use it again... Instead you're using an onPress function that declared inside the Artist component. You should check it out

Comment: Nice, glad it helped :)